# Erro simples ao tentar utilizar Hibernate + JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, persistência

Bom dia,
Estou iniciando a criação de um simples cadastro com Hibernate.

Tenho as seguintes classes

**Ligacao.java**
http://pastebin.com/vgDn9U3Y

**hibernate.cfg.xml**
http://pastebin.com/06kA87Lv

**Ação do form**
http://pastebin.com/2iPB1HU1

E ao executar o gravar ele retorna o seguinte:

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.HibernateException
/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
at
org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2093)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2074)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
```

Alguém poderia ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: O erro parece ocorrer por não encontrar o arquivo xml. Tem certeza que ele se encontra na pasta resources?

Comment: Gustavo, sou meio novo e não sei se estou te respondendo certo. Como é apenas um cadastro teste eu não trabalhei com mvc e os diretorios está organizado da seguinte forma:
...\Controlador 2.0\src\linx\
Aqui dentro tem todos os arquivos inclusive o xml

Comment: Sem problemas cara, todo mundo tem, um dia, que aprender, essa é a lei. No caso de arquivos de configuração, existem locais especificos para estarem, como o pom.xml, ou o web.xml, em projetos web. O hibernate.cfg.xml precisa estar na pasta src/main/resources, senão ñ será lido e codificado para o classpath. Tenta criar essa estrutura de pastas ai.

Comment: Gustavo, muito obrigado, fui mecher nas propriedades do projeto e adicionei a pasta do package chamado Linx, apos isso resolveu e funcionou normalmente. Parece que ele tava procurando os arquivos na src porém o projeto tava em um pacote com nome de Linx.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ViniciusLeonardo Hoje em dia praticamente só usamos o arquivo persistence.xml. Depois dá uma estudada a respeito.